# GridLayout and number of rows and columns

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout

Does GridLayout ever not honor the number of rows and columns you've specified if you don't fill it completely?

I'm creating a GridLayout with 3 rows and 4 columns.  However, I'm only adding 9 components.  It ends up showing me these 9 components in a 3x3 grid, rather than a 3x4 grid (with only 1 component on the third row (and two blanks)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just fill empty cells with empty items (like a `JLabel`), eg:

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame
{
    MyFrame()
    {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,4));

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
            this.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(""+i));
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            getContentPane().add(new JLabel());

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This layouts them as

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
9
```

Comment: -1, although the solution works it is more of a hack and does not demonstrate an understanding of the API. Also if you really need an empty cell, then it would probably be better to use one of the Box components (glue, strut) which don't have any special painting logic and are just designed to fill space.

Comment: I don't get your point.. my answer explains inners of the `GridLayout` API. Its intent is to provide a way to display an equal grid of objects and an empty `JLabel` is perfectly legal, I don't understand why it should be a hack.. from documentation: _The GridLayout class is a layout manager that lays out a container's components in a rectangular grid._ So it is supposed to work with `row*col` elements.

Comment: Did you read my answer? The API allows for you to specify a 4 column grid. If both row and column are entered, then the column is ignored. Its a hack because of the creation of "empty items" to achieve the desired result. If the GridLayout was declared properly there would be no need for these empty items.

Answer (score 32):

> rather than a 3x4 grid (with only 1 component on the third row (and two blanks)).

Then you should be creating your GridLayout using:

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(0,4));
```

It tell the layout that you don't know how many rows you have, but you want 4 columns. So the columns will be filled up before moving to the next row.

No need for empty components.