# Either Editing BorderLayout or Making a Custom LayoutManager

Tags: java, layout-manager

Okay, so another question for the day. 
I want to have a BorderLayout, where I have the logo at the top, and not three, but four columns in center. Is there a way for me to edit the BorderLayout manager, or do I just have to make one myself? (And if I have to make one myself, where would I start, as I've never made my own before?)

My code at the moment, no text or anything fancy like that added in yet (Although I tried adding in the image, and for some odd reason, it's not working, hopefully I'll figure that out.)

```
   public static void createGUI(){
  JFrame programFrame = new JFrame("Warlords Organizer");
  programFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  Icon backgroundIcon = new ImageIcon(IMAGE_PATH);
  JLabel contentLabel = new JLabel(backgroundIcon);
  contentLabel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  File imageFile = new File(IMAGE_PATH);
  File imageFile2 = new File(IMAGE_PATH2);

  //Warlords Logo JLabel
  Icon logoIcon = new ImageIcon(IMAGE_PATH2);
  JLabel warlordsLogo = new JLabel(logoIcon);
  warlordsLogo.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  //JFrame programFrame Constructors
  programFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  programFrame.setContentPane(contentLabel);
  programFrame.pack();
  programFrame.setVisible(true);
  programFrame.setResizable(false);
} // public static void createGUI() Closing
```

(The problem with the logo isn't the filepath, as I have that referenced in code I didn't post.)

So yeah, sorta 2 questions at once;
What did I do wrong with the logo?
and
How can I edit (or make) a layout to fit it to where I have the top (like the BorderLayout PAGE_START), but 4 columns in the center?

EDIT:
I apologize if I didn't have enough information to be helped, I'm not really sure what other code I could have provided.
I decided to go with this, I hope it works -

```
   //Makes the Initial BorderLayout
  JPanel allContent = new JPanel();
  allContent.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  //New JPanel for GridLayout 
  JPanel fourRows = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,4));
  fourRows.setLayout(new GridLayout());

  allContent.add(warlordsLogo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  allContent.add(fourRows, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

I'm pretty sure putting the layout on JPanel fourRows and then doing fourRows.setLayout is redundant though.

My final intent is to have the logo at the top, and four columns in the center where I can add panels and buttons. I used (0,4) because I'm not sure how many rows I'm going to end up with, as per here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5657131/1676781

Anything I can do to fix my code? (Which is here) -

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainFrame {


//Image Paths
private static final String IMAGE_PATH = "imageFolder/warlordsOrganizerBackground.png";
private static final String IMAGE_PATH2 = "imageFolder/warlordsLogo.png";

//Making the parts for the GUI
public static void createGUI(){
  JFrame programFrame = new JFrame("Warlords Organizer");
  programFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  Icon backgroundIcon = new ImageIcon(IMAGE_PATH);
  JLabel contentLabel = new JLabel(backgroundIcon);

  File imageFile = new File(IMAGE_PATH);
  File imageFile2 = new File(IMAGE_PATH2);

  //Warlords Logo JLabel
  Icon logoIcon = new ImageIcon(IMAGE_PATH2);
  JLabel warlordsLogo = new JLabel(logoIcon);

  //Makes the Initial BorderLayout
  JPanel allContent = new JPanel();
  allContent.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  //New JPanel for GridLayout 
  JPanel fourRows = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,4));
  fourRows.setLayout(new GridLayout());

  allContent.add(warlordsLogo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  allContent.add(fourRows, BorderLayout.CENTER);

  //Add ScrollPane MAKE SURE TO ADD TO new JScrollPane WHERE IT NEEDS TO BE / TEXT
  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
  scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
  scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

  scrollPane.setOpaque(false);
  scrollPane.getViewport().setOpaque(false);

  //JFrame programFrame Constructors
  programFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  programFrame.setContentPane(contentLabel);
  programFrame.pack();
  programFrame.setVisible(true);
  programFrame.setResizable(false);

} // public static void createGUI() Closing

public static void main(String[] args) {
  javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        createGUI();
     } //public void run() Closing
  });
}
}
```

Comment: *"not three, but four columns in center"*  There is only one 'column' in the `CENTER` of a `BorderLayout`.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I think he's talking about the vertical center of the layout and not about `BorderLayout.CENTER`. So `EAST`, `CENTER` and `WEST`.

Comment: @DeadlyJesus  *" I think he's talking about"*  ..an SSCCE speaks louder than words.  (And I'm more interested in information than speculation.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson DeadlyJesus got what I meant, but what I meant was incorrect. Landei nailed exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only `NORTH`, `CENTER` and `SOUTH` of the `Borderlayout`. In the `CENTER`, put a `JPanel` with a 4 column `GridLayout`.

Comment: I didn't think of it like that, thanks. I need to get into the programming mindset, it's been a while since I've dusted off Java (Today is my first day back in it.) Thanks for bearing with my silly questions, I'll end up using -
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0,4));